# What is the equivalent to @Any in JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, orm

In hibernate The @Any annotation is used to define the any-to-one association, which can point to one of several entity types.
Is there an equivalent to @Any annotation in JPA?

Comment: I've checked the docs since I've never had the need for such annotations, and I didn't see anything regarding an "@AnyToOne", there's only the usual "@ManyToOne",  "@OneToMany", "@OneToOne", etc...

Comment: `@Any` is hibernate specific. There is no JPA equivalent as it is not defined in any specifications. So if you want to use it, then you need to use hibernate

Answer (score 3):

As the documentation says:

> This is not the usual way of mapping polymorphic associations and you
>   should use this only in special cases (e.g. audit logs, user session
>   data, etc).
>
> Source:
>   http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-any

So usually there is no need for such an association and can be solved with normal JPA inheritance. That's why it's not part of the JPA spec.

Comment: This answers the question, but misunderstands the reason.
The "you're doing it wrong" part of this answer assumes that the set target objects is closed and part of the same type hierarchy.

Those are pretty hefty assumptions and If you don't make them the purpose of @any becomes pretty clear and JPAs lack of them pretty annoying.